# View my account as others see it

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

How would one go about displaying a link on a user's profile page (users/uid) so when logged in user, who is the owner of this account clicks on the link, she is presented with a page with no edit account privileges, ie same as other users see it?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the user should not be able to edit his own account details??

Comment: Well, I will have different layout/data in user-profile.tpl.php for account owner and as other users see it without having the 'edit own account' permission. So when account owner would like to view her profile as other users would see it she may click this link and do so while still being logged in

Comment: Yes, and her page should be displayed as a public profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest that you can take a look at [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels). Enable the module and you will see a `Panels` tab under `Structure`. There are two ways for you to achieve this:

1. You can go to `Panels` and create a variant for the `User Profile` page. This will edit the default view that is provided to the user when he visits his own profile page.
2. If you don't want to make changes in the default view then, you should create a new `Panel page` and then you can place a link for it on your website which will display all the information of the current logged in user into it. This option provides you much more control on what all information you want to display on your page.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Shekhar, thank you for the answer, however this doesn't help in my situation. What I need is the following: for example my uid is 1 so if I am on my profile page while logged in (or any other page which would display a cloned profile page) which is website_url/user/1 Drupal treats me as the visitor and not the owner of the account with uid 1. Pls. let me know if you get the idea.